# reduce java inheritance hierarchy

Tags: java, inheritance

This question asked in an interview regarding inheritance hierarchy. Consider we have a long chain of hierarchy for inheritance.
[image]

1. Is it good to maintain long chain of inheritance hierarchy?
2. If it is no. In java how can we reduce it?

Above one just an example.

Comment: Asking *“Is it good to maintain long chain of inheritance hierarchy?”* is a bit like asking *“Is it good to use too much sugar?”*  The question is already highly biased and I doubt there is a useful answer.

Comment: If people take the time to answer your question do not then change your question such that the answers no-longer reflect the question.

Answer (score 2):

Monthly Paid and Hourly Paid should not be classes, but at best interfaces. To answer your question, yes, a long "chain" is good. But only as long as it still makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would say that "Monthly Paid" and "Hourly Paid" should not inherit from Engineer as the frequency that someone is paid is not a type of Person. Instead the Class Person should have a member "PayFrequency". This is called "Composition" rather than "Inheritance".

One reason for doing this is that you might also have a Doctor who is paid monthly. Then you would need two Classes "Monthly Paid" which clearly wouldn't work.

The problem is not one of the length of the inheritance chain. You should make your chain as long as you need so long as it is a good fit for the data you are trying to model.

Comment: Well now my answer doesn't fit the question you asked. Thanks for wasting my time.

Comment: your answer made me think about misunderstanding of my question. no one can survive without mistakes. sry again.

Answer (score 0):

The question was probably about classic design patterns, such as **composition** and **delegation**.

For example, a person could have a *job*. The person has a name; but it doesn't become a different kind of person because of its job. Instead, job-specific functionality is *delegated* to the job object.